# React setState not updating the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I'm new to React and I'm having some trouble with changing sate with `setState` method. I'm trying to update state of ToDo item when I click on the checkbox. When I'm debugging `handleChange` method it changes the state of the item for a while. Unfortunatelly, the final state is like at the beginning (state of the checkbox is never changed). Does somebody know where the problem is?

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        todos: todosData,
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }


handleChange(id){
    this.setState(prevState => {
        const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
             if (todo.id === id) {
                  todo.completed = !todo.completed
             }
             return todo
        })
        return {
            todos: updatedTodos
        }
      })
    }


render()  {
    const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(item => <ToDoItem key={item.id} todoItem={item} 
    handleChange={this.handleChange}/>) 

  return (
       <div className="App">
         {todoItems}
       </div>
   );
}

}

export default App;
```

Here is my ToDoItem component:

```
import React from 'react'

function ToDoItem(props){
    return (
        <div className = "todo-list">
            <div className = "todo-item">
                <input type="checkbox" 
                    checked={props.todoItem.completed} 
                    onChange = {() => props.handleChange(props.todoItem.id)}/>
                <p>{props.todoItem.text}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ToDoItem
```

Comment: Did you start your project with `react-create-app` ?

Comment: Yup. I started my project this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this handler and let me know if works.

```
handleChange(id){
    const list = this.state.todos.slice();
    const index = list.findIndex(o => o.id === id);
    list[index].completed = !list[index].completed;
    this.setState({ todos: list });
}
```

Comment: Oh, it works! But what's the main difference in this kind of solution?

Comment: Well, not sure I am not at PC. But just don't complicate your life. Slice is creating new array. Find index is lambda which will find element fast and then setState is obvious. This approach is based on official react guide how to udpade list states.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
   handleChange(id){
     this.setState(prevState => {
        const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
           if (todo.id === id) {
               todo.completed = !todo.completed
           }
           return { ...todo }; // need to return a new object
        })
        return {
            todos: updatedTodos
        }
      })
    }
```

`todo`s are objects and event if `todos` are being set as a new object every time, its items referencing to the same object, and it is used by `ToDoItem`.

Comment: updatedTodos is an array with this change that I made. I think that problem is laying somewhere in the second return statement.

Comment: @Shadov Have you tried running the code above? (Just to be sure that it's not the case)